# How to compare SQLite Column against a user string?

Tags: java, sqlite, comparison

I am creating a JFrameApplet (In Java) with a log in (SQLite) but I am struggling to understand how to compare a wanted username, against a username that is already taken:

For Example: I want the username JoeBloggs, but it is taken, how do I compare a wanted username against one already made.

I have an SQLite users.db and the field is USERNAME.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching up the UNIQUE constraint.

When creating a table use`CREATE TABLE Users(Id INTEGER, USERNAME TEXT UNIQUE);`

so if `JoeBloggs` is already an entry in the db trying to add it again with `INSERT INTO Users VALUES(2, 'JoeBloggs');` will give you an `Error: column USERNAME is not unique`.